# Edit FASTA header using sed

Tags: fasta, bash, linux

I need to rename the following headers from a FASTA file. Something like:

```
>ENST00000488147.1::chr1:29570-30013(-)
>ENST00000405392.5::chr2:24919186-24920186(-)
```

into different format like this:

```
>chr1:29570-30013(-)_ENST00000488147.1
>chr2:24919186-24920186(-)_ENST00000405392.5
```

How can I rename the FASTA headers, perhaps using `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: Is there fasta sequence between the headers? If so is it multiline or single line fasta? Also what about Biopython?

Comment: Hi Michael. Yes, there are fasta sequences between the headers, and it has a large number of fasta sequences alongside their headers for each. I didn't know anything about Biopython, but I just looked it up and it seems really helpful as it has motif analysis tools (MEME or MAST). Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
awk -F "::" '{if($1~">"){gsub(">","");print ">"$2"_"$1} else {print $0}}' foo.fa
```

Basically the same as from Devon but using `-F` to indicate the initial field delimiter and then using `gsub` to remove the `>`.

Comment: Hello ATpoint. Thank you for your answer. I should've used `gsub` instead of `sed` to remove the string that I don't want. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 8):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="::"}{if($1~">"){printf(">%s_%s\n",$2,substr($1,2))}else{print $0}}' input_file.fa > output.fa
```

An explanation of the non-obvious bits:

- `BEGIN{FS="::"}` split columns using :: as the designator
- `$1~">"` If there's a > in the line
- `substr($1,2)` Trim the `>` that was at the beginning of the line.

Comment: `awk -F:: '{sub(/>/, ">" $2 "_"); print}' KDM4A_1kbp_TSS.fasta > KDM4A_1kbp_TSS_swp.fasta
        sed 's/::chr.*)//' KDM4A_1kbp_TSS_swp.fasta > KDM4A_1kbp_TSS_MEMEinput.fasta` I just checked your answer now. I had tried working by myself and come up with this script. But, yours looks much better than mine :) I appreciate it for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

`sed -E 's/>(.+)::(.+)/>\2_\1/' in.fa > out.fa`

If you want to use sed.

Comment: This misses the `>` at the beginning of each name:

`sed -r 's/>(.+)::(.+)/>\2_\1/'` for linux and 
`sed -E 's/>(.+)::(.+)/>\2_\1/'`  for macOS.

Comment: Sorry there was a little typo. Now it should work properly

Answer (score 2):

I would use `perl` here instead of `sed` so you can use non-greedy patterns (e.g. `.*?`) and so ensure that you always match the *first* occurrence of `::` if there are more than one on the line. Perl also has `-i`, and in fact is where sed got the idea from, so you can edit the file in place just like you can with `sed`.

Using this example file:

```
$ cat file.fa
>ENST00000488147.1::chr1:29570-30013(-)
ACCTCTGAGAGCACCTCTGAGAGCACCTCTGAGAGCACCTCTGAGAGC
ATATATCGGCATATATCGGCATATATCGGCATATATCGGCATATATCG
>ENST00000405392.5::chr2:24919186-24920186(-)
ACTCTAGGATATCGCGATATCGCCTTAGGCTAGAATCGGCTTAGC
TCGCGATATCATCGCCTTAGGCTAGAATCGTCTAGGATATCGCG
CCTTAGGCTATCATCGCCTAGAATCGTCTAGGATATCGAATC
```

You can do:

```
$ perl -pe 's/>(.+?)::(.*)/>$2_$1/' file.fa 
>chr1:29570-30013(-)_ENST00000488147.1
ACCTCTGAGAGCACCTCTGAGAGCACCTCTGAGAGCACCTCTGAGAGC
ATATATCGGCATATATCGGCATATATCGGCATATATCGGCATATATCG
>chr2:24919186-24920186(-)_ENST00000405392.5
ACTCTAGGATATCGCGATATCGCCTTAGGCTAGAATCGGCTTAGC
TCGCGATATCATCGCCTTAGGCTAGAATCGTCTAGGATATCGCG
CCTTAGGCTATCATCGCCTAGAATCGTCTAGGATATCGAATC
```

Or, to edit the file in place:

```
$ perl -i -pe 's/>(.+?)::(.*)/>$2_$1/' file.fa 
$ cat file.fa
>chr1:29570-30013(-)_ENST00000488147.1
ACCTCTGAGAGCACCTCTGAGAGCACCTCTGAGAGCACCTCTGAGAGC
ATATATCGGCATATATCGGCATATATCGGCATATATCGGCATATATCG
>chr2:24919186-24920186(-)_ENST00000405392.5
ACTCTAGGATATCGCGATATCGCCTTAGGCTAGAATCGGCTTAGC
TCGCGATATCATCGCCTTAGGCTAGAATCGTCTAGGATATCGCG
CCTTAGGCTATCATCGCCTAGAATCGTCTAGGATATCGAATC
```

#### Explanation

- `perl -pe`: **p**rint each line of the input file after applying the script given by `-e` to it.
- `s/>(.+?)::(.*)/>$2_$1/'`: the `s/old/new/` is the substitution operator and will replace `old` with `new`. Here, we look for the shortest stretch of one or more characters (`.+?`) from the `>` until the first occurrence of `::`, and capture it as `$1` (because the pattern is in parentheses). Everything after the first `::` is then captured as `$2` (`(.*)`). Then, we replace everything we matched with a `>`, then the 2nd captured pattern, an underscore and the first captured pattern.

---

Just for fun, here's a golfed awk approach:

```
$ awk -F'::' '$0=sub(/>/,"")?">"$2"_"$1:$0' file.fa
>chr1:29570-30013(-)_ENST00000488147.1
ACCTCTGAGAGCACCTCTGAGAGCACCTCTGAGAGCACCTCTGAGAGC
ATATATCGGCATATATCGGCATATATCGGCATATATCGGCATATATCG
>chr2:24919186-24920186(-)_ENST00000405392.5
ACTCTAGGATATCGCGATATCGCCTTAGGCTAGAATCGGCTTAGC
TCGCGATATCATCGCCTTAGGCTAGAATCGTCTAGGATATCGCG
CCTTAGGCTATCATCGCCTAGAATCGTCTAGGATATCGAATC
```